# When using async task and await to download files why the first file is taking almost 30 seconds to download?

Tags: c#, winforms

then after the first file it's downloading all the rest of the files in the links fast but the first one take a lot of time.

the button click event to start the downloading.

```
private async void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CreateDownloadFolders createDownloadFolders = new CreateDownloadFolders();
            createDownloadFolders.GenerateDownloadFolders(textBoxRadarPath.Text, textBoxSatellitePath.Text);

            lblStatus.Text = "Preparing Downloads";
            loadingLabel1.Visible = true;
            radar.PrepareLinks();
            await satellite.DownloadSatelliteAsync();

            downloadLinks.AddRange(radar.links);
            downloadLinks.AddRange(satellite.links);

            loadingLabel1.Visible = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < downloadLinks.Count; i++)
            {
                if (downloadLinks[i].Contains("Radar"))
                {
                    lblStatus.Text = "Downloading radar images";
                    await DownloadFiles(downloadLinks[i], Path.Combine(textBoxRadarPath.Text,
                            $"RadarImage{countRadarImages + 1}.gif"));
                    countRadarImages++;
                }
                else
                {
                    lblStatus.Text = "Downloading satellite images";
                    await DownloadFiles(downloadLinks[i], Path.Combine(textBoxSatellitePath.Text,
                            $"SatelliteImage{countSatelliteImages + 1}.gif"));
                    countSatelliteImages++;
                }
            }
        }
```

i used a break point and it's getting very fast to the for loop :

```
for (int i = 0; i < downloadLinks.Count; i++)
```

then i added another break point in the DownloadFiles method : and it's getting fast to the line :

```
await webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(URL, location);
```

this is the DownloadFiles method

```
public async Task DownloadFiles(string urlAddress, string location)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                webClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0 Chrome");
                webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(((sender, e) => Completed(sender, e, sw)));
                webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler((sender, e) => ProgressChanged(sender, e, sw));

                Uri URL = new Uri(urlAddress);

                sw.Start();
                try
                {
                    savedFile = location;
                    await webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(URL, location);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string err = ex.Message;
                }
            }
        }
```

but then it's not getting to the progress changed event and the completed event

```
private void ProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e, Stopwatch sw)
        {
            string downloadProgress = e.ProgressPercentage + "%";
            string downloadSpeed = string.Format("{0} MB/s", (e.BytesReceived / 1024.0 / 1024.0 / sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds).ToString("0.00"));
            string downloadedMBs = Math.Round(e.BytesReceived / 1024.0 / 1024.0) + " MB";
            string totalMBs = Math.Round(e.TotalBytesToReceive / 1024.0 / 1024.0) + " MB";

            // Format progress string
            string progress = $"{downloadedMBs}/{totalMBs} ({downloadProgress}) @ {downloadSpeed}"; // 10 MB / 100 MB (10%) @ 1.23 MB/s
            textProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            textProgressBar1.CustomText = progress;
        }

        private void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e, Stopwatch sw)
        {
            if (e.Cancelled == true)
            {
                sw.Stop();
            }

            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                filesCounter--;
                File.Delete(savedFile);
                if(filesCounter == 0)
                {
                    lblStatus.Text = "Downloading Finished";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                filesCounter--;
                sw.Stop();
                if (radar.links.Count == 0)
                {
                    sw.Stop();
                }
            }
        }
```

after the line

```
await webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(URL, location);
```

it's just hanging not freezing the application just hanging for almost 30 seconds and then start downloading the rest of the files very fast.

why at the first time it's hanging/waiting so much time and not downloading all the files?

Comment: Do you have network issues, DNS resolution slow maybe?

Comment: Have you tried to change the order of the files? (to see if it's one particular file that's causing problems).